# Disable "conflicted copy" feature on Dropbox for certain files

Tags: dropbox

When I write software and store it in my Dropbox, I get lots of object (.o) files at compile time.

Occasionally, my computer is not connected to the internet, and then when I continue working on another computer, and rebuild the software, I get another set of object files, but since the old ones weren't synced, it will occasionally create "conflicted copies" of the files.

Now this feature is obviously quite useful for most files, but for object files, it is useless, and kind of annoying, since they can be rebuilt and I don't care about their versions.

Is it is possible to disable this feature for object files?

Comment: You can vote on this feature so that DropBox might implement it in the future. It is often requested...

Comment: @Billy ONeal: they get created in the same folder as the source files and automatically synced.

Comment: Okay.. out of source builds then :) They're better anyway :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it is possible to disable this feature for object files?

Nope.